# Why can't an application access the content provider of a different application if the two have the same sharedUserId?

Tags: android, permissions, android-contentprovider

Okay I have two applications.  Alpha and Beta.  Alpha has an exported Content provider.  Alpha and beta have the same string value.

> android:sharedUserId=com.app.sharedId

If the app 'Beta' also has this value set in the AndroidManifest.xml, it cannot access the content provider.  I get the following callstack:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.geoff.messenger.app/com.geoff.messenger.app.activities.SelectRecipientActivity}:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2184)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
>               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
>               at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>        Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
>               at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:224)
>               at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:164)
>               at com.geoff.contacts.app.providers.MyContactsProvider.query(MyContactsProvider.java:45)
>               at android.content.ContentProvider.query(ContentProvider.java:857)
>               at android.content.ContentProvider$Transport.query(ContentProvider.java:200)
>               at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:461)
>               at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:404)
>               at com.geoff.messenger.app.activities.SelectRecipientActivity.setupContentResolver(SelectRecipientActivity.java:51)
>               at com.geoff.messenger.app.activities.SelectRecipientActivity.onCreate(SelectRecipientActivity.java:28)
>               at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
>               at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2148)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
>               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
>               at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

I don't understand why having the same sharedUserId would be a problem for accessing a Content provider.  I also don't understand why the error message doesn't hint much at the problem.

Someone commented that the issue may lie in the query method of my content provider.  The code for that is here:

```
public Cursor query(Uri uri, String[] projection, String selection, String[] selectionArgs, String sortOrder)
    {
        SQLiteQueryBuilder builder = new SQLiteQueryBuilder();
        builder.setTables(UserContract.TABLE_NAME);

        // TODO use Uri matcher to parse the URI, but for now it's just 'all'
        SQLiteDatabase database = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = builder.query(database, projection, selection, selectionArgs, null, null, sortOrder);
        return cursor;
    }
```

Comment: `sharedUserId` has nothing to do with a `ContentProvider`. You seem to have a problem with the provider itself, in your implementation of your `query()` method.

Comment: When i removed the sharedUserId from the application that was trying to use the provider, the query succeeded.  So It seems like it has SOMETHING to do with it.  Anyway, I have a barebones query() implementation in my content provider.  Let me know if you see an issue.

Comment: "When i removed the sharedUserId from the application that was trying to use the provider, the query succeeded" -- if you change `sharedUserId` on an app, you must uninstall and reinstall the app. So must all your users. Hence, I **strongly** discourage the use of `sharedUserId`.